# Stockfish's algorithm

Tags: analysis, checkmate, stockfish, open-source

I'm trying to understand how Stockfish thinks, how it calculates the best move.
I'm reading open source code, but it's not clear. I want to know, should I know some theory about algorithms to understand that code? Or is it possible without knowing anything? If there are important algorithms, please tell me what I should learn before reading source code.

Comment: what exactly is not clear. You would be surprise, but playing chess requires non-intuitive algorithm. Yes you need to know something about algorithms to understand complicated algorithms and also you need to understand artificial intelligence (another surprise)

Comment: I like surprises )) it's interesting, thanks i'll read about it.

Comment: take a look at this book (I read it and in my opinion it is good). http://www.amazon.com/Artificial-Intelligence-Modern-Approach-Edition/dp/0136042597 and about this algorithm which is used in chess http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning but also in huge amount of other AI tasks.

Answer (score 6):

If you are reading the code to become a better player, you won't have much luck. The tricks used are only useful when you have the memory and computational power of a machine.

If instead you are reading it to learn about chess programming, the following wiki is a great resource https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com

Comment: I'm programmer, so i know that men can't calculate like computer )) It's interesting for me, how programs can examine positions, also this'll improve my knowledge about programming (by reading code). Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 2):

TSCP is well commented and a good place to learn how chess programs work
http://www.tckerrigan.com/Chess/TSCP/

Answer (score 1):

Before starting diving into stockfish why don't you checkout the smallest chess program in C called nanochess by Oscar Toledo. It has only one file main.c